# What a set of GPS coordinates means?

Tags: gps, coordinates, distance

I have a set of GPS coordinates 12.9611159,77.6362214. What exactly do these mean? How can I convert them to degrees of longitude and latitude? What formula should I use to get accurate distance between two sets of coordinates when the order of distance is 10km.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely 12.9611159 is the latitude in degrees, 77.6362214 the longitude. In that case, the coordinate is in India. If latitude and longitude are reversed, you end up in the Greenland Sea.
You can easily check this by entering the coordinate pair in the Google maps search box. Google expects latitude first.

For the distance, in python you can easily use the haversine package:

```
from haversine import haversine

my_coord =  (12.9611159,77.6362214)
other_coord = (12.9, 77.6)
distance = haversine(my_coord, other_coord)
```

This will give you the distance in km.

Comment: Does ruby have a function like that?